# Input wrapping in flexbox for unknown reason

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to align a `label` inline with a text `input` and have them stay on the same line in a flex container that will change widths. If I make the container smaller, like 200px, it wraps the input. Make the container 400px width, and it doesn't wrap. I can't figure out why the input wraps, but if I set its width smaller to say 100px, it stops wrapping. I can't do that. The reason I need wrapping is for the third element that needs to always wrap to the following row.

I can't change the HTML structure.

```css
#test {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

#test label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#test input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  line-height: 18px;
  min-width: 0;
  /* width: 100px; */
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <label>Label text:</label><input type="text" value="Stay inline!" />
  <span>Third element to wrap to next line.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the input to shrink its width to fit with the label?

Comment: @code, yes.....

Comment: Can you use grid?

Answer (score 1):

You can try CSS grid.

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "label input"
    "text text";
}

#test label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  grid-area: label;
}

#test input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 18px;
  grid-area: input;
}

#test span {
  grid-area: text;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <label>Label text:</label>
  <input type="text" value="Stay inline!" />
  <span>Third element to wrap to next line.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question. I can't change the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex` as normal, but for the `span`, you can use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) `flex: 1 1 100%;`. For the input, give it a width, say `width: 100px;`, or less with `flex-grow: 1;`.

```css
#test {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

#test label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#test input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  line-height: 18px;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  width: 100px;
}
#test span{
  flex : 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <label>Label text:</label><input type="text" value="Stay inline!" />
  <span>Third element to wrap to next line.</span>
</div>
```

The problem with your `input` was that it has a fixed width by default, so you need to set a smaller width to it.

Comment: I didn't know inputs had a default width, but that makes sense. I think this is a simplest answer, and what I was trying for.

Answer (score 1):

I found a non-grid solution: You can set `width: 0` for `input` while keeping its `flex-grow: 1`. To make the third element wrap, set a `flex-basis` of `100%` for it and prevent it from shrinking/growing.

```css
#test input {
  width: 0;
}

#test span {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

Do note that this won't work if `#test`'s width is smaller than that of `label`.

Try it:

```css
#test input {
  width: 0;
}

#test span {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

/* Original styles */

#test {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

#test label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#test input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <label>Label text:</label>
  <input type="text" value="Stay inline!" />
  <span>Third element to wrap to next line.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 elements and flex wrap applies to all of them, letting all of them move around. If you want input to stay inline with label you will have to group it.

In some point label and input will forced by size of size of `#test div` to stack, to avoid this and force them to overflow `#test`, you can apply `display: flex` without allowing wrap. Here is my implementation:

```css
#test {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

#test label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#test input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  line-height: 18px;
 width: 200px;
}

.form-field{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <div class="form-field"> <label>Label text:</label><input type="text" value="Stay inline!" /></div>
  <span>Third element to wrap to next line.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: But why would the input wrap when there's nothing affecting it's width? Why would it behave differently at different container widths when there is no width set for it?

Comment: There is width set to #test div. If you apply "border: 1px solid red" to #test you will see that when size of lable + input approaches #test size it stacks to avoid overflow since you are applying "flex-wrap: wrap" on the container.

Comment: Apparently the OP cannot change the structure of the HTML...

Comment: @Max, I can see the size/border of the input, but I don't know what is setting that size. It's not like it gets down to where the text runs out of room, it wraps well before that.